# comparing different resolutions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have a question about weak factorization of birational maps (in characteristic zero).

If $X_1 \to X_2$ is a birational map of smooth varieties, it was proved some time ago that we can decompose it into a sequence of blowups and blowdowns with smooth centers.

Now, suppose that $X_1, X_2$ are resolutions of the same $Y$, so they admit a birational morphism to $Y$. Can we find a factorization into blowups and blowdowns so that on each intermediate step we also have a morphism to $Y$? Is this written up somewhere?

Comment: Did you look into the book of Kollar?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If $X_{11} \to X_1 $ and $X_1 \to Y$, then of course, $X_{11} \to Y $.  Certainly that isn't your question.  I assume I'm being dense, but could you clarify ?

Comment: @aginensky.  The issue is that for a birational contraction / dilatation / blowing down $X_i\to X_{i+1}$, if $X_i$ admits a morphism to $Y$, perhaps $X_{i+1}$ does not admit a morphism to $Y$.  Yet for the next link in the chain, say $X_{i+2}\to X_{i+1}$, it may again happen that $X_{i+2}$ admits a morphism to $Y$.

Comment: Hi Jason, I must be confused about OP's syntax.  Of course what you say is correct.  But I read his statement with the indexing i going in the opposite direction. His $X_1$ appears to be at the bottom of the chain, not the top.  I'm sure I'm just confused by something obvious.

Comment: Actually, just looked at the weak factorization theorem closer, and it actually says that all intermediate varieties up to some point map to $X_1$ and after that point they map to $X_2$. So in particular, each of them does map to $Y$. 

Should work on my reading skills :-)